# Who is the only pre-teen that has traveled to outer space?

Tags: lateral-thinking, history, outer-space

Who is the only pre-teen that has traveled to outer space? Sort of a trick question.  But also not quite a trick question.  This is a **person**, not a dog or chimpanzee or other animal.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preadolescence) pre-teen means 10-13 years old. Is that your definition too? Or is it any age less than 13? Or something else?

Comment: The first definition would work.

Comment: if the first definition works, so does the second.  [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preteen) says preteen is a boy or girl not yet 13 years old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it perhaps

> Jack Lousma?

Reasoning

> Jack was an astronaut born in **29** February 1936 and traveled to outer space in April 1966, which would mean he had 7 birthdays, making him a "pre-teen".

Comment: Your reasoning contains an incorrect statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, 7 years old doesn't match the definition of pre-teen.

Answer (score 4):

Building off Prim3numbah's response,  I reason that the answer is again

> Jack Lousma

Where Prim3numbah messed up in their reasoning:

> While Jack Lousma did travel to outer space in April 1966, he was the commander of STS-3 starting from March 22 - 30 **1982**, at which time he would have been **11**! This qualifies for the definition of pre-teen being from 10 - 12.

I suspect this puzzle was posted today because:

> This week started on March 22nd, which is also the first day that Jack Lousma spent as Commander on STS-3.

Comment: Your 3rd box also contains an incorrect statement.

Comment: @Jiminion fixed now?

Comment: Ha, ha, no.  Not really. 2nd box has incorrect statements.

Comment: @Jiminion tell me... does the 1st box have incorrect statements?

Comment: No, it does not.